# what is the pressure in Neptune where the density reach 1g/cm^3?

Tags: neptune

from [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11214-020-00660-3/figures/3) graph, it looks like it should be around 20000km from the center. So it is about 0.8 radius.

However, I cannot imagine this is correct. The pressure is probably only a few bar at that height. And it is mainly hydrogen. How can the hydrogen at this pressure has density of 1g/cm^3? Even considering the low temperature it has there, it is still impossible.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Why do you say "only a few bar".  This graph would suggest a pressure of about 400 bar at that depth https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Uranus-and-Neptune-pressure-profiles-as-a-function-of-normalized-radius_fig3_231059682

Comment: Why don't you follow the links in the image description? They link to papers who model it. The arxiv.org versions are freely accessible

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP just appears to disagree with published data for no apparent reason.

Comment: @JamesK thanks, my bad, somehow i miss read the axes of the pressure vs radius in another paper